# MonoMac Package Does NOT Include Images

Tags: macos, monomac

I have several images and one application icon in my MonoMac application, all with build action set to "content", but when I build the installer (.pkg) file and install it on another machine, none of the images are available! Is this because I'm using the free version of MonoDevelop instead of Xamarin Studio? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1: On the test machine, I went into "Show Package Contents/Resources" and manually changed the permissions on the images from "Everyone - No Access" to "Everyone - Read/Write", and now the images are available in the application! The obvious problem is: how do I build the package so the images are installed with these rights? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to get my images to show up by moving them into the resources folder and changing some path information. I still can't get my application icon to work correctly, but I'll post that question separately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the build action to `BundleResource`

Comment: No luck -- still only default application icon, and nothing for the other images. The weird thing is this:If I do "View Package Contents", the images exist in both the resources and MonoBundle folders, but all I see are the default images. The target system won't show the actual image itself -- it's like it's a permissions issue or something?